# Spotify dockerfile could't push image, resource is deined

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, spotify-docker-client

I am using Spotify Dockerfile maven plugin like this

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>push</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <username>myUserName</username>
                    <password>myPassword</password>
                    <repository>dockerhubUsername/dockerhubRepo</repository>
                    <tag>latest</tag>
                    <buildArgs>
                        <JAR_FILE>${project.artifactId}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                    </buildArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

So whenever I build using `mvn deploy` I get this error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.4.10:push (default) on project nepse-sim: Could not push image: denied: requested access to the resource is denied -> [Help 1]
```

I have specified my dockerhub username and password there in the configuration but still I am getting this error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try to use another tag, something never used before.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni Still the same error

Answer (score 3):

First of all, Do not put your credentials in pom.xml because this will be in git or whatever you are using. So add your credentials in settings.xml inside .m2 folder.

```
<server>
    <id>docker.io</id>
    <username>xxxxx</username>
    <password>xxxxxx</password>
</server>
```

Change your configuration tag in pom.xml as below -

```
<configuration>
    <repository>dockerhubUsername/dockerhubRepo</repository>
    <tag>${project.version}</tag>
    <useMavenSettingsForAuth>true</useMavenSettingsForAuth>
    <buildArgs>
        <JAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
    </buildArgs>
</configuration>
```

Then It should work.